# Best approach to read English books for non-English speaker

Tags: grammar, usage, conjunctions

I'm student in computer science field and all my books wrote in English, so I'm not enjoying reading books that I don't understand most of their meaning, I always open google translate to understand as much I can.

But this not useful at all, and it's so pain.

How i can improve myself with that or mastering reading books in English like I do with my native language?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on how to improve one's English.

Comment: Take an English course, and read as many books as possible appropriate to your level of comprehension.

Comment: @Mick Thanks, I've did that, i think there should be some steps to  improve this statue.

Comment: You may need to read books that you consider to be beneath your dignity, such as children's (or young adults') books. There really is no magic bullet. Read books that stretch you, but not too much. English language films with subtitles may also be useful. Watch the films enough times to be familiar with the dialogue, then turn the subtitles off.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that many of your school books are available in electronic editions.  At [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=es&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&text=nicely#en/zh-CN/good%20luck%20with%20schooling%20in%20English!), instead of entering *text* to translate, **you can also enter a URL or a local filename, and it will translate the entire document.**  (Google has size limitations but there are other translate services too.)  There is also a [Google website translator](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en) (intended for businesses but I think it's free too.)

- [Here is a PDF I found online, translated into Chinese](https://translate.google.ca/translate?sl=en&tl=zh-CN&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Ftug.org%2Ftexshowcase%2Fcheat.pdf&edit-text=&act=url).

I'm sure some publishers will charge you for an electronic copy of the book (E-edition), but many are available for free online (some legally, some pirated).

- [Here is a Google filetype search for (free) PDF Files online about Computer Science  Theory](https://www.google.ca/search?&q=computer%20science%20theory%20textbook%20filetype%3Apdf).
- [Here is a search for free E-books about Computer Science Theory on Google Books](https://www.google.ca/search?q=computer%20science%20theory&dcr=0&tbs=bkv:r,bkt:b&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=Xdpr=1).  (Note the drop-down to select Free Books, Any Books, Free Previews, etc) and [a different type of search from Google Books](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&source=hp&q=book%20list%20for%20computer%20science%20and%20engineering&oq=book%20list%20for%20computer%20sc).

Certain books in the last course I took had a code inside the back cover that I could enter at the publisher's website to download a free E-copy (since I had already purchased the regular book).

Many "legal" and "illegally copied" e-books are available through Torrent hosting sites (downloading from torrents require an app like [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/win)).

- [Here is a search for Computer Science books on thePirateBay](https://thepiratebay.org/search/computer%20science/0/99/601).
- Here is [a Google filetype search for torrents for Computer Science books](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=computer%20science%20theory%20filetype%3Atorrent).

I can't imagine how frustrating it must be to have to learn a language just to learn another language (like coding languages)...

*Good Luck with your schooling*!